# Let $k < l$, and let $\mathbb{R}^k \subseteq \mathbb{R}^l$, is the subspace topology on $\mathbb{R}^k$ the same as the standard topology?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Let $k < l$, and let $\mathbb{R}^k \subseteq \mathbb{R}^l$, is the subspace topology on $\mathbb{R}^k$ the same as the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Let $(\mathbb{R}^l, \mathcal{K})$ and $(\mathbb{R}^k, \mathcal{T})$ be $\mathbb{R}^k$ and $\mathbb{R}^l$ equipped with the usual topologies, and let $(\mathbb{R}^k, \Omega)$ be $\mathbb{R}^k$ equipped with the subspace topology.

Now the basis elements of $\mathcal{T}$ are of the form $V = B_{(\mathbb{R}^k, d)}(x, \epsilon)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$. Since $\mathbb{R}^k \subset \mathbb{R}^l$ and $V$ is also open in $(\mathbb{R}^l, \mathcal{K})$ and $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ it follows that $V$ is open in $(\mathbb{R}^k, \Omega)$. So that $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \Omega$.

However proving that $\Omega \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ is giving me a bit of difficulty. I know that $\Omega = \{ W \cap \mathbb{R}^k | W \in \mathcal{K}\}$, hence $Z = B_{(\mathbb{R}^l, d)}(a, \epsilon) \cap \mathbb{R}^k \in \Omega$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}^l$. If $a \in \mathbb{R}^k$ then automatically I would have $\Omega \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ but we could also have $a \not\in \mathbb{R}^k$, in which case I'm unsure how to prove that $\Omega \subseteq \mathcal{T}$.

Comment: Even though you have a straightforward embedding of $\mathbb{R}^k$ into $\mathbb{R}^l$, it is not correct to say that $\mathbb{R}^k$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^l$.

Comment: Since R^k is NOT a subset of R^l, pick a specific embedding of R^k into R^l.  Perhaps using that embedding will clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For $k<l$ identify $\mathbb R^k$ with $\mathbb R^k\times \{0\}^{l-k}$ by identifying $x\in \mathbb R^k$ with $x\times \{0\}^{l-k}.$

For $x\in \mathbb R^k$ and for $r>0,$ we will denote the open ball of radius $r,$ centered at $x,$ in the Euclidean metric by B^{(k)}(x,r), which is then identified with $B^{(k)}(x,r)\times \{0\}^{l-k}.$  In $\mathbb R^l$ denote the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x^*=x\times \{0\}^{l-k},$ of radius $r,$ in the Euclidean metric, by $B^{(l)}(x^*,r).$

We have $$B^{(l)}(x^*,r)\cap (\mathbb R^k\times \{0\}^{l-k})=B^{(k)}(x,r)\times \{0\}^{l-k},$$ which is identified with $B^{(k)}(x,r).$